# Grails - how to call a controller method from a form

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp

I'm completely new to grails, and I appreciate any help. 
This code is in my gsp file:

```
<g:form action="backfillMachineTags">
            <fieldset class="buttons">
                <g:submitButton name="create" class="save"
                                value="${message(code: 'default.button.create.label', default: 'Create')}"/>
            </fieldset>
        </g:form>
```

And this code is in my RegressionPoolMachineController.groovy file:

```
def backfillMachineTags()
    {
        flash.message = "testing message"
        redirect(action: "list")
    }
```

But when I click the submit button on the form, the method is never entered and I get a 404 not found.

message:/pool-manager/regressionPoolMachine/backfillMachineTags

status:  The requested resource is not available.

I also tried doing:

```
<g:form url="[action:'backfillMachineTags',controller:'RegressionPoolMachineController']">
```

but get a similar 404 not found.

Am I missing a step to connect my form and controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a "controller" attribute to your form in addition to the "action" attribute.  You could use url instead of controller and action, but you would need something like
`url="${createLink(controller: "myController", action: "myAction")}"` instead of what you've shown here.

For reference: http://docs.grails.org/2.5.6/ref/Tags/form.html

You can also look at the generated HTML in your browser (just view source) and see what is actually being generated on the resulting web page.  That's usually pretty helpful for finding out why things aren't going where you want them to!

Comment: To explain a little more: the controller by default is whatever controller got you to the page.  So it's optional, but strongly recommended (in my experience anyway) since you might later in your project get to that page from some other route, and specifying a controller never hurts!

Answer (score 3):

Try to use the following:

```
<g:form controller = "controllerName" action ="actionName" >
    <fieldset class="buttons">
        <g:submitButton name="create" class="save" value ="${message(code: 'default.button.create.label', default: 'Create')}"/>
    </fieldset>
 </g:form>
```